# Optimal use of intermediate results in a functional program

Tags: haskell, optimization, functional-programming

Suppose I have two computations which could use the same intermediate result. If I wrote an imperative program, I would pass the same (relatively) "global" state to both functions, to be more efficient.

When writing functional code, I would use a function that computes the intermediate value as part of both functions which need that value. Should I be expecting my compiler to optimize that function call, or is there a more intelligent way for me to design the program?

To clarify, here's an example.

Let's say I have a function to compute some property `a` after a long and tedious computation. From `a`, I need to calculate two other properties `b` and `c`. For eg: `b = a^2` and `c = a^7 + a^(1/7)`. Now, as part of my main program, I invoke the functions to compute `b` and `c`. Will the computation to find `a` be done exactly once and the result reused, or will `a` be computed multiple times?

Ps: In case it's relevant, I'm learning Haskell.

Comment: Hmm, I'm afraid I don't follow. Especially the part about passing a function to an intermediate value (which you're saying is analogous to the intermediate value in the imperative program you were talking about in the first paragraph). Could you post a concrete example?

Comment: Haskell is lazy, so it will typically create those "intermediate" results by itself.

Comment: There's no problem applying multiple functions to the same value, and the value will only be calculated once.

Comment: I've added a concrete example. Does that help, or is it still too broad?

Comment: @AndrewC: Wrt my example, the compiler will compute $a$ only once, rather than once each while computing $b$ and $c$?

Comment: (Use backticks instead of dollars for code.) Yes it'll do `a` just once.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that answers my question.

Comment: It will be computed only once, if it's type is monomorphic. Consider your intermediate function returns a value of type `Num a => a`, then to compute `b` you need an `Integer` while to compute `c` you need a `Double`, then the computation of `a` has to be repeated  (although it should be repeated even in an imperative program, in the general case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Suppose I have two computations which could use the same intermediate result. If I wrote an imperative program, I would pass the same (relatively) "global" state to both functions, to be more efficient.
>
> When writing functional code, I would use a function that computes the intermediate value as part of both functions which need that value. Should I be expecting my compiler to optimize that function call, or is there a more intelligent way for me to design the program?

So to be concrete, you have two functions which both compute the same thing as part of a sub-computation. E.g.

```
f x = y + 3
   where
      y = x ^ 2

g x = y * 7
   where
      y = x ^ 2

z = f 2 + g 2
```

So you want to "float out" the common subexpression, `x ^ 2`, and share it.

This is ["common subexpression elimination"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination). It is an optimization a compiler can performn, or something you can do by hand. GHC, a Haskell compiler, [will do CSE in some cases](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC_optimisations#Common_subexpression_elimination). In other cases, you can do it by hand by naming the intermediate computation explicitly.

It's better when the compiler does it.